# Which Notes-apps featuring notes that stick to the desktop are available for Unity

Tags: 13.10, software-recommendation, notes

I'm looking for something like stickynotes or xfce4-notes. I read the former is not supported anymore. Does the latter work well in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

stickynotes works on 14.04.  I'm using it now, it's pretty cool, similar to the Windows7 desktop widget stickies.

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-indicator-stickynotes-0-4-2-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1012-1012-04-linux-mint-161413-and-elementary-os-0-2/